# How can one define "punctured torus" in Homotopy Type Theory? Is its fundamental group the free product of the integers with themselves?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-type-theory, torus

**Questions.**

1. Has the beautiful old idea, in part already known to Gauß, of a *punctured torus surface* (take, if you will,  the classical set-theoretic definition as the meaning of the latter three words) been defined in *Homotopy Type Theory* already? If yes, how? If not, are there any *choices* in doing so or is one more or less forced towards a definition of "punctured surface"?
2. More specifically, has the classical isomorphism<sup>1</sup>

$\pi_1(\text{punctured torus})\cong \mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$

been *proved in Homotopy Type Theory already*?

3. Can one somehow 'conceptually' *predict*  'how' different from $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ the answer could at worst be?

**Remarks.**

- Homotopy Type Theory has of course reached tori already (see [Chapter 6 herein](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)), more generally, arbitrary finite CW-complexes. 
  But he punctured torus is not compact.
- Part of my motivation for asking this question is that I had occasion to explain to someone what it means that $S_{1,1}$ is not simply connected. Moreover, I try to teach myself a little Homotopy Type Theory. 
  So I tried to find out what Homotopy Type Theory has to say on punctured surfaces, yet found myself at a loss to even *define* 'punctured torus'. 
  This may very well be due to my inexperience with Homotopy Type Theory.
- As a needless ornament to round out this question, here is an animation of first puncturing an immersion (torus surface)$\to$ $\mathbb{R}^3$, then running through a 1-parameter indexed family of regular homotopies of said immersion, and finally mending the puncture again:

[image]

(source: adapted by myself from [this German Wikpedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punktierter_Torus), which, incidentally, *wrongly* calls this an 'eversion' of the torus: while eversion of a torus *is* possible, by utilizing one of the famous eversions of the sphere, *this* is not one, I think, for the crude reason that here the non-continuous operations of puncturing and un-puncturing are part of the animated gif; incidentally, someone with a Wikipedia account should perhaps correct this, if it is correct that calling this an eversion is wrong.)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Usually proved, needless to say, via homotopy-invariance of $\pi_1$, by simply describing, in one way or the other, a homotopy-equivalence between $S_{1,1}$ and $S^1\vee S^1$, then combining three things: homotopy-invariance of $\pi_1$, the fact that $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and (a corolllary of) van Kampen's theorem. 
My understanding is that a suitable van Kampen theorem has already been proved in Homotopy Type Theory, and, as is widely known, two pioneers of this theory [have](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2012/06/07/a-simpler-proof-that-%CF%80%E2%82%81s%C2%B9-is-z/) [proved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3443) that $\pi_1(S^1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.I also take it that homotopy-invariance of $\pi_1$ is not an issue at all in Homotopy Type Theory; holds by design. Also, Homotopy Type Theory already *offers pushouts of spans in the category of groups*, so it seems that the (hoped-for) result $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ has been constructed in the theory, already, so somehow it seems that all what is missing is a *definition* of the punctured torus.</sub>

Comment: There is no way to define "puncturing" as an operation in HoTT, since it is not a homotopy-invariant thing.  And as you note, the homotopy type of the punctured torus is $S^1\vee S^1$, which has been defined and its homotopy group computed in HoTT.  So I'm not sure what more one could ask for.

Comment: @MikeShulman: thank you very much. Thinking about it, it indeed seems rather *misguided* to ask how to define *an operation which changes the homotopy type* in Homotopy Type Theory. If you make your comment an answer, I for one would accept it.

Comment: In principle one could ask for a homotopy pushout involving the wedge of two circles resulting in a torus and see that one gets the correct analogue as in the topological model.

Comment: @PeterHeinig That's not quite it; any nontrivial operation will *change* the homotopy type!  What's misguided is to ask about operations that are not *invariant* with respect to homotopy type of the input.

Comment: @DavidRoberts There is such a homotopy pushout: the description of the torus as a HIT with one point-constructor, two path-constructors, and one 2-path-constructor.  The first three constructors are a wedge of two circles; the last constructor glues in the 2-cell wrapping around each of them twice that makes it a torus.  I suppose, based on this example, one might consider "puncturing" as the non-operation of exhibiting a space as obtained by attaching a single cell to another space (the "punctured" one).

Comment: Many thanks for these insightful and instructive comments.